# I want to add month to a Date using SqlContext

Tags: scala, apache-spark

'**01-FEB-2013**' This is my date. how can I get the result as 01-MAR-2013?

`SELECT DATE_ADD( '2011-01-01', INTERVAL 1 month );`

This is possible by mySql.I want the result using sqlContext in scala Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

You will want to use `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.add_months`:

```
def add_months(startDate: Column, numMonths: Int): Column
"Returns the date that is numMonths after startDate."
```

Here is an example of its usage:

```
scala> val df = sc.parallelize((0 to 6).map(i => 
       {now.setMonth(i); (i, new java.sql.Date(now.getTime))}).toSeq)
       .toDF("ID", "Dates")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [ID: int, Dates: date]

scala> df.show
+---+----------+
| ID|     Dates|
+---+----------+
|  0|2016-01-21|
|  1|2016-02-21|
|  2|2016-03-21|
|  3|2016-04-21|
|  4|2016-05-21|
|  5|2016-06-21|
|  6|2016-07-21|
+---+----------+

scala> df.withColumn("New Dates", add_months(df("Dates"),1)).show
+---+----------+----------+
| ID|     Dates| New Dates|
+---+----------+----------+
|  0|2016-01-21|2016-02-21|
|  1|2016-02-21|2016-03-21|
|  2|2016-03-21|2016-04-21|
|  3|2016-04-21|2016-05-21|
|  4|2016-05-21|2016-06-21|
|  5|2016-06-21|2016-07-21|
|  6|2016-07-21|2016-08-21|
+---+----------+----------+
```

Comment: No problem, if you found this answer useful please [upvote/accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: If  my data is in this format 2016-FEB-02 .and need to change to 2016-MAR-02 .  then how to solve?

Comment: Are your dates strings or `java.sql.Date` objects? If you have a question about string to date conversions, start looking [here](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/09/16/apache-spark-1-5-dataframe-api-highlights.html). If you are stuck you can ask a new question here on SO (and I could help you there). If this current answer satisfies your current question, please accept it.

Comment: Ok evan I tried it with one query like "select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(add_months( from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2015-JAN-01' ,'yyyy-MMM-dd'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'),1),'yyyy-MM-dd'),'yyyy-MMM-dd');" its working .

Comment: @Ajith if my answer satisfied your question, please accept it